# QGIS 3.28.11 problem with duplicates in atlas generator

Tags: qgis, print-composer, atlas, atlas-generator

In QGIS i have a shapefile with around 2000 polygon features. Attribute table has 3 columns: Field, Type and cover. Each polygon feature has a unique field number. There are 163 types. For each field, all the existing types and their cover (three classes, 1 2 and 3) in that field is listed:

```
Field   Type   Cover 
1       A      1
1       B      1
1       C      2
2       A      1
2       B      1
2       C      3
3       A      1
3       B      3
3       C      1
```

Above is a simplified attribute table. My actual table has 2000*163 (Fields * types) rows. Important to note is that there is only one geometry field 1, 2, 3 etc. up to 2000. But i generated the geometry for every type so i can use distinct cover values per type per polygon/field.

I generate an atlas, which works great. Except, i also get 2000*163 maps generated. This is a problem when exporting to pdf, since it takes forever and the system crashes all the time. Furthermore, after map 163, the exact same maps are generated again.

How can i make it so that all the dublicates in "Type" are removed from the export and i get only one map per "Type". So, 163 maps in total.

Help is much appreciated and if more information is needed i'm happy to deliver that.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.
I added rownumber as an extra column (ID). I then used the 'filter' in the atlas generator to filter only for the first 163 rows.

"ID" >= 1 AND "ID" <= 163

This works.